# How to convert a string to a buffer of 16 bytes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, character-encoding, byte

I'm new in Python and I'm looking to convert a normal string to a byte object. Basically how do i go about turning something like "abcdefghijk" into this format b'\xa2\x9a\xb8.\xdc_\xbb\xc4\x1e\xc9S\x0fm\xac\x86\xb1'

I have tried using the bytes() function and several other encoding options.

Comment: Please provide some code that you have tried so others can better understand the problem.

Comment: I get this error - "struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 16 bytes" whenever I use a string so I'm looking to covert the string to the required format for the code I intend to run

Comment: In the example used a variable was assigned to a value in this format - b'\xa2\x9a\xb8.\xdc_\xbb\xc4\x1e\xc9S\x0fm\xac\x86\xb1' but when I switch the value to a string, I get the error above, so I'm looking for a way to convert my string value to the required format.

Comment: just edit your question, paste some code that you have tried.